Simplify Expansions of Binomials
Given the expansion $a^{10}+30a^9b+405a^8b^2+...+59049b^{10}$. Express this in the form of $(a+b)^n$. Does the expansion need to be expanded further in order to solve? I am unsure of how to start this question. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Do you mean in the form $(x+y)^n$? because the unknown $a,b$ are used in the expansion. Or you really mean $(a+b)^n$?

Welcome to Math SE. First, can you determine what $n$ must be? Next, note your question is somewhat confusing as it seems the $a$ and $b$ in your $a^{10}+30a^9b+405a^8b^2+...+59049b^{10}$ and in $(a+b)^n$ are not necessarily the same. It seems the $a$ and $b$ in $(a+b)^n$ were meant to be generic, although as Angae's comment indicates, they should have used different variables to avoid possible confusion, e.g., the suggested $x$ & $y$. As it's stated, the $a$ can remain the same, but not the $b$ (in fact, the one in $(a+b)^n$ is an integral multiple of the one in the expansion instead).

@AngaeMT Looking for the form of $(a+b)^n$ as I am looking for the values of $a$ & $b$ such that once the value is found & in the form of $(a+b)^n$ I would be able to use the formula for binomial expansion to reproduce the expansion I have posted here. I'm not overly well versed in mathematics so I'm not sure of the differences between those 2 forms I'm just looking to "undo" the expansion to get to the algebraic identity generally described as $(a+b)^n$. Hope this clears things up.

@VulpesInculta According to your reply, it seems like you want the form "$(x+y)^n$". Note that $(a+b)^n=a^{10}+\cdots+b^{10}$ is a fixed stuff in terms of $a,b$, but more likely you want to find some $x$ and $y$ such that $(x+y)^n=a^{10}+\cdots+59049b^{10}$. The only problem is that $a,b$ are used in your original statement, so you need to search for other variable to describe the unknowns you want.

@JohnOmielan Sorry for the confusion, looking for the generic form so in this case $(x+y)^n$. I'm not sure how I would be able to solve for $n$ in this case without knowing the value of either the variables $a$ or $b$. I was thinking I could take the $10th root$ of $59049$ which gives $3$. But after solving for that & removing the value of $b=3$ from the other integers. When I take the root of the other numbers to find $a$ I get different values each time. Not sure if this is relevant or correct.

@VulpesInculta No worries. Regarding how to solve it, Parcly's comment already provides the answer, which is the same as what I got. As for how to solve it, consider the binomial expansion. The first term of $a^{10}$, and last one of $59049b^{10}$, indicate the exponent, i.e., $n$. Also, the coefficients of $a$ and $b$ (for the $x$ and $y$ terms in $(a+b)^n$) come from those terms, apart from possibly the sign, with the second and third terms of the provided expansion confirm that both coefficients are positive.

@JohnOmielan So could my whole answer be summed up by taking the tenth root of 59049, yielding 3 & applying it to $(x+y)^n$ to get $(x+3y)^10)$ without defining $x$?

@VulpesInculta Note the $x$ & $y$, as used there, are generic placeholders, meant to be replaced by appropriate multiples of powers of $a$ & $b$. In your case, we could have $x$ be a multiple of $a$, which due to $a^{10}$, & the next $2$ terms confirming $a$ is to the first power & the coefficient, i.e., $1$, is positive. Thus, $x=a$. Similarly, get $y$ in terms of $b$. Note I've already basically provided more help, and explanation, than I'm supposed to do in comments, so this will have to be it. Nonetheless, I hope that I, & the others here, have helped you understand how to solve this.

Guys, thanks for closing.   This is very helpful.  It's easy for a yuen, dubuque or Gao, hence begets a downvote.

This would be $(a+3b)^{10},$ by the binomial theorem. Just expand:  $$\sum_{i=0}^{10}{10\choose i}a^{10-i}(3b)^i.$$
We should have $3^{10}=59049.$

I'm sorry that I have such a hard time understanding the concepts. I feel sorry for all who try to help. I do not understand why $k$ is there as a third variable in this answer. I have found $b$ by taking the 10th root of $59049$ for a value $b=3$. After factoring that out I try to solve for $a$ but get different values for $a$. I don't know how to solve for $a^10$ when I don't know the value it is supposed to yield. I have only ever been taught to expand from $(x+y)^n$ & not from summation notation. I understand if you are not interested in helping further though. Thank you for your answer.

It's ok.  Actually my answer was edited  by Graham to include $k.$  I knew it was $3$ by using the theorem and looking at the first few terms.   Don't be hard on yourself.   Mathematics is a difficult subject.

So is $(a+3b)^{10}$ the official answer? If that's the case I can understand that, as the value of $b$ is pretty much given. If $a$ also needs to be defined then it will be much more difficult for me. My only question if $(a+3b)^{10}$ is the answer would be, why is $b$ still included after the value is found?

Try writing it out: ${10\choose 0}a^{10}+{10\choose 1}a^9(3b)^1+{10\choose 2}a^8(3b)^2+\dots +(3b)^{10}.$  $a$ and $b$ are variables, and can be anything.

Thank you very much. I understand much clearer now in the "choose" format. You have been very helpful. I hope you have a lovely nychthemeron.
